# Why do I get more than 25 symbols in plot in 25-fold cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation

I have a group of observations, 25, And I want to perform a 25-fold cross-validation (leave-one-out).

Here is my code,

```
library(MASS)
min.m <- lm(formula= Mass ~ 1, data=mean.mydata)
fsel.m <- step(min.m, direction = "both", scope=sel.fmla, steps = 5)

fsel.fmla <- as.formula(object=fsel.m)

# Leave-one-out rule validation
library(DAAG)
cross.m <- suppressWarnings(cv.lm(df=mean.mydata, fsel.fmla, m=25, legend.pos=FALSE))
```

This is my plot,

[image]

Can anyone explain me why there is more than 25 symbols?

I noticed there is 2 of each ones, does it correspond to cross-validation results (cvpred) and predicted data?

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on SO. Although it is couched in terms of `R` code (& will require that potential answerers can read the `R` code), this Q is really about what is going on, not about how to code in `R`. Moreover, the code implies confusion about variable selection and cross validation. Clearing up that confusion is what would truly constitute answering this question.

Answer (score 2):

The `cross.m` object belongs to class of type data.frame. Therefore, one needs to plot columns Mass and cvpred (which are the predicted values in the cross validation) to reproduce the desired plot.

See the example below:

```
#reproducible example
mean.mydata = data.frame(Mass=c(1,2,3),var_a=c(4,5,6),var_b=c(7,8,9))

library(MASS)
min.m <- lm(formula= Mass ~ 1, data=mean.mydata)
fsel.m <- step(min.m, direction = "both", steps = 5) #removed scope argument
fsel.fmla <- as.formula(object=fsel.m)

# Leave-one-out rule validation
library(DAAG)
cross.m <- suppressWarnings(cv.lm(df=mean.mydata, fsel.fmla, m=25, legend.pos=FALSE))

class(cross.m)
[1] "data.frame"

head(cross.m)
Mass var_a var_b Predicted cvpred
   1     4     7         2    2.5
   2     5     8         2    2.0
   3     6     9         2    1.5

plot(cross.m$cvpred,cross.m$Mass,pch=19)
```

[image]